# Is it possible to run existing data driven selenium script into JMeter

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I  want to run  existing  data driven selenium test cases into JMeter. 
what other info should i provide to make my question more meaningful?

What i have tried:
convert selenium script into jar and  and paste it into jmeter/lib/junit. Run through JMeter. But its not working.

Comment: Did you try to add WebDriver plugin and follow tutorials?

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

When you face an issue with your JMeter script get used to check *jmeter.log* file, normally it should contain all the necessary troubleshooting information.

1. Be aware that JMeter doesn't contain any Selenium Java libraries so you will need to [download them](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and put into [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Given your tests are "data-driven" you should also copy all the necessary data to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. There are some limitations on JUnit test classes, i.e. they should have either empty [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) or constructor having an empty string

I would also recommend checking out [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more information on JMeter and JUnit integration.